# Configure Apache 2 to specify the same error documents for both 403 (Forbidden) and 404 (Page Not Found) responses

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I'd like to know how to configure Apache 2 to specify the same error documents for both 403 (Forbidden) and 404 (Page Not Found) responses.  I assume there is a directive to add to httpd.conf, but not sure what it is.

Most of the tutorials I see for doing this are based around .htaccess files, but I want to set this directive globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in a block like:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /40x.html
ErrorDocument 404 /40x.html
```

into the server or virtualhost configuration.

Here's the relevant section of the documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument

Answer (score 2):

You can set this globally in httpd.conf with the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
```